# Polite way when you ask someone you don't know a question

Tags: questions, writing, email

Which is the best way to ask a question in a polite way; for example, I want to write an email to someone that doesn't know me, and to ask something...

Is okay to say write this:

> Sorry to disturb you, Can I ask you a question about "something"?

Comment: Do you want to write "something" or is "something" a space for [something] else to go?

Comment: I didn't mention the real subject, is just something  that could be anything. @PeterDavidCarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're writing would probably be fine, though it would depend on the person you are writing to and anything you know about them might affect your choice. For example:

> Sorry to disturb you... Can I ask you a question about [something]?

Would likely be fine and a half-way house between formal and informal, which would seem likely appropriate in this situation.

You could also try:

> Hi, you don't know me but I'd like to ask your opinion on [something].

Or:

> I found your details/e-mail address [somewhere] and I was wondering if it would be ok to ask you [something]...

There are probably others too, but these would usually all be perfectly acceptable.